# Dash: Adding a scatter to a plotly express line

Tags: python, charts, callback, plotly-dash

On the following code, I want to add a new series to the existing chart.

```
 def update_graph_compare1(app):
    @app.callback(
    Output("world-rank-graph", "extendData"),
    Input("class_radios2", "value"),
    [State("date-range", "start_date"),
     State("date-range", "end_date"),
     State("world-rank-graph", "figure")]

    def update_graph_data(athlete_id,fig):

        rows = dataset.get_worldrank_evolution(boat_id=athlete_id, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
        df = pd.DataFrame([[ij for ij in i] for i in rows])
        df.rename(columns={0: 'position', 1: 'season', 2: 'release_date'}, inplace=True)
        df = df.sort_values(['release_date'], ascending=[1])    
        fig.add_scatter(x=df['release_date'], y=df['position'], mode='lines', name='Athlete 2')
        
        return fig
```

But it gaves the error "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'add_scatter'"

How can I define fig as plotly express line chart, so I can add the scatter.

Thank you very much

Comment: You need to fix the callback arguments. From the Input+States in the decorator and the variables in the function body, you should have `update_graph_data(athlete_id, start_date, end_date, fig)`.